# Flutter: Stop scrolling from animateTo function

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

**
Question: How to stop scrolling of function animateTo?
**
According to I set controller for SingleChildScrollView

```
SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            controller: _scrollController
```

When I click button scroll. It will scroll down to bottom slowly but function

```
 _scrollController.animateTo(
            _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
            curve: Curves.linear,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 80000),
          );
```

I would like to click a button to stop the scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable `var endPos` and `var animDuration`
Replace your code's value with the following
 `_scrollController.animateTo( endPos, curve: Curves.linear, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: animDuration), );`

When you click on start  alter the values to scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent and animDuration 8000.

When stop is clicked update the values as
scrollController.position.pixels and animDuration as 100.

Comment: It's work but I have to call the animateTo again. So it will be effect performance or anything If user click many time?

Comment: No, just updating the position of the scroll would not affect the performance.

Comment: @NitiphoneXayaseng to stop scrolling just call `_scrollController.position.hold()` method - this is a method to hold pending scrolling activity